# testing in the console

Tags: prolog

The consult `?- go(c, g).` returns false, but states true for `?- go(a, d).`. I do not actually understand it, as I have added the proper rules, and for most of them it works.

Here are the statements I'm using:

```
door(a, b).
door(b, c).
door(c, d).
door(b, e).
door(e, f).
door(e, g).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom):- 
    door(FromRoom,ToRoom).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom):- 
    door(ToRoom, FromRoom).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom) :-  
    door(FromRoom, NextRoom),
    go(NextRoom, ToRoom), !.

go(FromRoom, ToRoom):-
    door(ToRoom,NextRoom), 
    go(NextRoom, FromRoom), !.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add accumulator to your predicate to avoid got stuck in inf loop.

```
door(a, b).
door(b, c).
door(c, d).
door(b, e).
door(e, f).
door(e, g).

go(From, To, T) :-
    T=[From|T1],
    go(From, To, [To], T1).
go(From, To,T, T) :-
    door(From, To),!.
go(From,To,T,T) :-
    door(To,From),!.
go(From, To, Acc,T) :-
    door(X, Do),!,
    \+ member(X, Acc),
    go(From, X, [X|Acc],T).
go(From,To,Acc,T) :-
    door(X,Z),!,
    \+member(Z,Acc),
    go(X,To,[X|Acc],T).
```

Comment: i can't change becus this is the plan we have to use its the rules which might be wrong

Comment: my question is that go(c, g). should say yes but why does it say no when i put it in the console

Comment: are you sure lets check... first 2 predicates will fail because there is no door(c,g) and there is no door(g,c) third predicate will also fail becouse there is only door(c,d). and there is not any door(d,X). third predicate will also fail becouse there is not any door(g,X).

Comment: there are only these 6 ways in which you can travel and you can also travel backwards so if you draw it then you will see how it will look like but i am still strggling with go(c, g). and why its coming up as no

Comment: this answer is corect. What do you need to see it? if you change door(b, e). that into door(d, e). then answer will be yes...

Comment: i know but the question is saying for me to use these 6 this is why i think my rules are wrong

Comment: there are not, there is no way from c to  g

Comment: that it why i added rules but i think some of my rules is wrong

Comment: add this go(FromRoom, ToRoom) :-  
door(NextRoom, FromRoom),
go(NextRoom, ToRoom),!

Comment: the rules in which i have provided above can you check which rule i shud change the answer you gave me gives something different

Answer (score 0):

You fourth rule should read

```
go(FromRoom, ToRoom):- 
 door(ToRoom,NextRoom), 
 go(FromRoom,NextRoom),!.
```

because you already swapped the search order in calling door/2, but this leads to looping, as rightly remarked by @whd. Here a version that 'returns' the path

```
go(Room, Room, Path, Path).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom, SoFar, Path) :-
    ( door(FromRoom, NextRoom) ; door(NextRoom, FromRoom) ),
    \+ member(NextRoom, SoFar),
    go(NextRoom, ToRoom, [NextRoom|SoFar], Path).
```

test:

[image]

```
?- go(c,g,[],P).
P = [g, e, b, c, d] ;
P = [g, e, b] ;
false.
```

Due to Prolog search order, it 'takes a tour' in `d` before going back. It's easy to avoid acting on the SoFar parameter at top level call...

Comment: the 4th rule you told me to change around NextRoom and FromRoom can you tell me why this should be done so then i can understand more better

Comment: sorry, I can't think anything clearer than what I already explained